# How to pass data, select for an array

Tags: c#, arrays

How to save the select data below into an array.

```
SqlConnection conConexao1 = clsdb.AbreBanco();
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select id, tamplete1, tamplete2 from usuarios ", conConexao1);
SqlDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

if (dr1.HasRows == true)
{
    if (dr1.Read())
    {
        id = int.Parse(dr1[0].ToString());
        templete1  = (dr1[1].ToString());
        templete2 = (dr1[2].ToString());
    }
}
```

I have already tried using foreach, but always passes the last table data.

Comment: use `while(dr1.read())` instead of `if(dr1.Read())`

Comment: right and put the array inside the while?

Comment: I don't see any array here

Comment: the array code was not passed, because the question is just this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a collection, `List` provide better flexibility than array.
The collection should be created outside the loop and the element should be added inside the loop.

```
List<Usuarios> list = new List<Usuarios>();
using (SqlConnection conConexao1 = clsdb.AbreBanco())
using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(
    "select id, tamplete1, tamplete2 from usuarios ", conConexao1))
using (SqlDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (dr1.Read())
    {
        list.Add(new Usuarios
        {
            Id = dr1.GetInt32(0),
            Templete1 = dr1[1].ToString(),
            Templete2 = dr1[2].ToString()
        });
    }
}
```

The class to imitate your data structure

```
public class Usuarios
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Templete1 { get; set; }
    public string Templete2 { get; set; }
}
```

if for some reason, you have to use an array as collection
`Usuarios[] array = list.ToArray();`

Comment: You can chain `using` statements to avoid some levels of nesting in your answer.